# Can Qt signals can be safely emitted from another QThread

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals-slots, qthread

I'm using some `QThread` in my application.

My objects "live" in different threads (their owner threads as Qt means it are different) and use signal/slots with queued connections to communicate.

Now, I have this problem :

- Object "A" lives in `QThread` "A"
- Object "B" lives in `QThread` "B"
- Gui lives in the "main thread"

then :

- Object "A" calls a method `B::foo` on "B" instance, from its own thread "A"
- the ressources shared by this `B::foo` method are protected using a mutex, no problem here to execute `B::foo` from the thread "A"
- inside the `B::foo` method, object "B" emit the signal `barSignal`

And I have some questions about his configuration :

- Is it safe to emit a signal of object "B" from a thread which is not the "B" owner's `QThread` ?
- Is it safe to use `Qt::AutoConnection` to receive this signal in a GUI object who lives in the "Qt main thread" ?
- Is it safe to use a `Qt::AutoConnection` to receive this signal in a object  "C" who lives in it's own `QThread` "C" ?

My test tends to say "yes" to everything.
By reading the Qt `emit` code, it seems to be ok.
But it didn't find anything in the Qt documentation about "*emitting signal from a thread which is not the emitter's owner thread*".

Answer (score 6):

It's safe to emit signals from other threads, *if you use auto or queued connections*. Auto is deduced to be *queued* in situations where the signal is emitted in a thread in which the receiving `QObject` do not have affinity. Direct connections are *not* thread safe.

There is a ["Signals and Slots Across Threads"](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html) section in the documentation that deals with emitting signals to objects in different threads.

> Queued Connection - The slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread. The slot is executed in the receiver's thread.

also

> The connection type can be specified by passing an additional argument to connect(). Be aware that using direct connections when the sender and receiver live in different threads is unsafe if an event loop is running in the receiver's thread, for the same reason that calling any function on an object living in another thread is unsafe.
>
> QObject::connect() itself is thread-safe.

Comment: There's also [a Qt wiki article](http://wiki.qt.io/ThreadsEventsQObjects) that I recommend to read for more background.